# Arel count on union results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arel

I have two tables ITEMS and ITEM_AUDITS.  An item can have 0 or more audit records associated to it.  Resource and status are required for fields and lookups.

I am trying to create a query that counts the number of occurrences of the item_id in both tables.  Effectively producing data that looks like the example below

```
Title   Item_ID     Count
ABC     1           2
ABC     3           4
Bible   5           1
```

I have been able to create a union query that produces the data without the counts:

```
  # Declare Arel objects
  i  = Item.arel_table
  ia = ItemAudit.arel_table
  s  = Status.arel_table
  r  = Resource.arel_table

  ######################
  # Build the item query
  ######################

  # Build the joins
  item = Item.joins(
    i.join(r, Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin).on(i[:resource_id].eq(r[:id]))
     .join(s, Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin).on(i[:status_id].eq(s[:id]))
     .join_sql
    ).uniq

  # Build the select columns
  #item = item.select('resources.title, items.id as id, count(*) as loan_count')
  item = item.select('resources.title, items.id as item_id')

  # Adds the where criteria  
  item = item.where(
    s[:title].matches("On Loan").or(s[:title].matches("Permanent Loan"))
    )

  # Add the group by clause
  item = item.group("items.id")

  ##########################
  # Build item history query
  ##########################

  # Build the joins
  item_audit = Item.joins(
    i.join(ia).on(i[:id].eq(ia[:item_id]))
     .join(r, Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin).on(i[:resource_id].eq(r[:id]))
     .join(s, Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin).on(i[:status_id].eq(s[:id]))
     .join_sql
    )

  # Build the select columns
  item_audit = item_audit.select('resources.title, item_audits.item_id as item_id')


  #######################
  # Union the two queries
  #######################

  report = item.union(:all, item_audit).select('title, item_id')
```

I can't progress past this to get the counts which should be something like

```
report = item.union(:all, item_audit).select('title, item_id, count(item_id)')
```

***EDIT***

The SQL I am trying to end up with is as below (a simple group and count on the union results).

```
select qry.title, qry.item_id, count(qry.item_id) from(
SELECT DISTINCT
    resources.title, items.id as item_id
FROM
    `items`
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    `resources` ON `items`.`resource_id` = `resources`.`id`
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    `statuses` ON `items`.`status_id` = `statuses`.`id`
WHERE
    ((`statuses`.`title` LIKE 'On Loan'
        OR `statuses`.`title` LIKE 'Permanent Loan'))
GROUP BY items.id 
UNION ALL SELECT 
    resources.title, item_audits.item_id as item_id
FROM
    `items`
        INNER JOIN
    `item_audits` ON `items`.`id` = `item_audits`.`item_id`
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    `resources` ON `items`.`resource_id` = `resources`.`id`
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    `statuses` ON `items`.`status_id` = `statuses`.`id`) as qry
group by qry.item_id
```

Anyone give me any pointers.

Many thanks,

Comment: I think it would be clearer what you want if you will provide the final sql you wish to obtain

Comment: I've changed the post to include the SQL required.